# How to pass an arraylist from an innerclass to another class that has already been started?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to retrieve an ArrayList from an async task. This async task is an inner class of another activity(OfflineBookingsFragment).
Calling the BackgroundTask2 from class TodaysBookingsActivity :-

```
OfflineBookingsFragment offlineBookingsFragment = new OfflineBookingsFragment();
            OfflineBookingsFragment.BackGroundTask2 backGroundTask2 = offlineBookingsFragment.new BackGroundTask2(getContext());
            backGroundTask2.execute();
```

To get the arraylist back to TodaysBookingsActivity I have made a method named setarraylist in class TodaysBookingsActivity:-

```
public void setarraylist(ArrayList<VendorBookingsSummary> SummaryArrayList) {
     summaryAdapter = new SummaryBookingsAdapter(getContext(), SummaryArrayList);     
        bookinglv1.setAdapter(summaryAdapter);      
        summaryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

The bookinglv is initialized in the class  TodaysBookingsActivity in onCreate. But it shows a null pointer exception in the method.

If we use an intent to send arraylist using Parcelable as:-

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, TodaysBookingsActivity.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("Birds", VendorBookingsSummaryArrayList);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

This error is received.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment OfflineBookingsFragment{987d75c} not attached to Activity
```

Comment: I am afraid you need to restructure your codes.

Comment: If you are using the `AsyncTask` in multiple activities or fragments, then you should remove that `AsyncTask` from the fragment and put it in its own class!